# How to write many equations on the left with labels and two row equations

Tags: equations, align, labels, multicolumn

I'm working on my thesis and i have several problems.... I try to build those equations which I put in the picture the same way on latex in my thesis but it doesn't work!

Here I give you my little code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Minimiere:} 
\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:eins}Z=c_{max} 
\end{flalign}

\textbf{unter der Nebenbedingungen}  
\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:fuenf}\hat{c}_{r,m,i}-\lambda{j,n}\cdot T_{n,m,i}-S_{m,i,n,p}-\Omega\cdot \bigl\lbrace\big(\sum\nolimits^{J_p}_{s=1}   \chi_{r-1,m,i,s,p}\big)+\chi_{r,m,i,j,n}\bigr\rbrace && \\
+2\Omega \geq \hat{c}_{r-1,m,i};\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n,p})|r>1 && \nonumber \\
\label{eq:sechs}\hat{c}_{1,m,i}-\lambda{j,n}-S_{m,i,n,0}\cdot A_{n,i}-\Omega(\chi_{u,k,l,j,n}+\chi_{1,m,i,j,n})+2\Omega \geq \hat{c}_{u,k,l}; && \\
\forall({u,k,m,l,i,j,n}|(l,i)\in E_{n}&& \nonumber 
\end{flalign}


Die Zielfunktion in Gleichung \eqref{eq:eins} soll die Produktionsdauer des Programms(schedule) minimieren, welches der Fertigstellungszeit des letzten zu bearbeitenden Sublots im System entspricht.Die Bedingungen in Gleichung \eqref{eq:fuenf} und \eqref{eq:sechs} sagen beide aus

\end{document}
```

[image: This what i want to build]

I'm totally new with latex and its hard for me with those special things to build....
Thanks!

Comment: dont understand your edit? can you tell me what you did ?

Comment: For code blocks use the `{}` button (which indents by 4 spaces) not back ticks (which Zarko did for you this time:-)

Comment: ah thank you, i just read code and then i used the other button!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want alignment at the top level so use `gather` not `flalign`, normally I'd use `split` for the two line terms but that doesn't flush left so I use `aligned` here although i have to say the layout seems very odd with the wrapped terms flush left and the `\sum\nolimits` Also don't use math italic for words such as `max`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Minimiere:} 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eins}Z=c_{\max} 
\end{equation}

\textbf{unter der Nebenbedingungen}  
\begin{gather}
\!\begin{aligned}&\label{eq:fuenf}\hat{c}_{r,m,i}-\lambda{j,n}\cdot
 T_{n,m,i}-S_{m,i,n,p}-\Omega\cdot \bigl\lbrace\bigl(\sum\nolimits^{J_p}_{s=1}   \chi_{r-1,m,i,s,p}\bigr)+\chi_{r,m,i,j,n}\bigr\rbrace \\
&+2\Omega \geq \hat{c}_{r-1,m,i};\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n,p})|r>1 \end{aligned}
\\
\!\begin{aligned}&\label{eq:sechs}\hat{c}_{1,m,i}-\lambda{j,n}-S_{m,i,n,0}\cdot
 A_{n,i}-\Omega(\chi_{u,k,l,j,n}+\chi_{1,m,i,j,n})+2\Omega \geq \hat{c}_{u,k,l};\\
&\forall({u,k,m,l,i,j,n}|(l,i)\in E_{n}\end{aligned}
\end{gather}


Die Zielfunktion in Gleichung \eqref{eq:eins} soll die Produktionsdauer des Programms(schedule) minimieren, welches der Fertigstellungszeit des letzten zu bearbeitenden Sublots im System entspricht.Die Bedingungen in Gleichung \eqref{eq:fuenf} und \eqref{eq:sechs} sagen beide aus

\end{document}
```

Comment: hey thank you David!   Now my Question is: is it possible to put all my equations in one gather environment? or how should i go on, because i want all the 16 equations labeld and written.. or just after \textbf{unter den Nebenbedingungen} everyone  is telling me another solution, im totally frustrated :/

Comment: yes that;s the whole point any consecutive run of equations should go in a single environment `gather`  if there are no alignment points `align` if not (`flalign` is _f_ ull _l_ ength alignment and rather specialist, although over used:-)

Comment: thanks but now how can i get the vertical space between those equations bigger?

Comment: @MiloLi you can increase `\baselineskip` or individually use `\\[20pt]` or whatever length you want to add at the end of each row

Comment: i worked with jot and that destroyed it in equation 5 and 6, but thanks for that solution! Thumbs up! i was sitting 3 days at this problem! should have met you before =) or get to know this nice community before. one other question how can i write \baselineskip like you ?

Comment: now i have a problem if  i add equation 7: \!\begin{aligned}&\label{eq:sieben}\hat{c}_{r,m,i}-\lambda{j,n}\cdot T_{n,m,i}-S_{m,in,p}\cdot A_{n,i}-\Omega\bigl\lbrace\big(\sum\nolimits^{Jp}_{s=1}\chi_{r-1,m,i,s,p}\big)+\chi_{u,k,l,j,n}+\chi_{r,m,i,j,n}\bigr\rbrace
&+3\Omega \geq \hat{c}_{u,k,l};\ \ \forall(u,r,k,m,l,i,j,n,p)|(l,i)\in E_{n} \ \text{und}\ r>1\\end{aligned} tex says there are many errors.... one is parapraph ended before gather wa scomplete . help ?

Comment: sorry the site doesn't really work asking additional questions in comments.but in the code there you look like you are missing `\\ ` before the `&`

Comment: i dit it the same way like you did before and now there are several errors...

Comment: @MiloLi paragraph error means you have a blank line which is never allowed in math mode

Comment: i edited with the new equation you may see it ;)

Comment: how can i get rid of the pagebreak? i made it, but now i have a page break after the first equation

Comment: @MiloLi see the amsmath documentation and in particular `\allowdisplaybreaks`